# How to filter rows based on group values in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with the following format

```
serialnumber,test,result
-------------------------
ABC          1    "TOO HIGH"
ABC          2    "PASS"
ABC          3    "TOO LOW"
DEF          1    "PASS"
DEF          2    "PASS"
DEF          3    "PASS"
```

I need to do two operations:

1) for each serial number that has all pass records, I need to roll it up into a single record

2) for every serial that contains a "TOO HIGH" or "TOO LOW" record, I need to exclude all "PASS" records for that serial number

How would I go about doing this in teradata 15, preferably in a single statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY
  -- #1, only PASS
  (     SUM(CASE WHEN result <> 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber) = 0 
    AND ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber
              ORDER BY test) = 1
  )
 OR
  -- #2
  (     SUM(CASE WHEN result <> 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber) > 0 
    AND result_ <> 'PASS'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a union query combining both conditions, using an aggregate query for #1 and a inner join query with derived tables for #2. Hopefully, Teradata's dialect supports the syntax:

```
SELECT  TableName.SerialNumber, 
        Min(TableName.Test) As Test, 
        Min(TableName.Result) As Result
FROM SerialNumber
GROUP BY SerialNumber
HAVING Sum(CASE WHEN TableName.Result='"PASS"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = Count(*)

UNION

SELECT  TableName.SerialNumber, 
        TableName.Test, 
        TableName.Result
FROM SerialNumber    
INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT SerialNumber FROM SerialNumber 
       WHERE TableName.Result = '"TOO HIGH"') AS toohighSub
INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT SerialNumber FROM SerialNumber 
       WHERE TableName.Result = '"TOO LOW"') AS toolowSub
ON toolowSub.SerialNumber = toohighSub.SerialNumber
ON TableName.SerialNumber = toolowSub.SerialNumber
WHERE TableName.Result <> '"PASS"';
```